# How In PhpStorm 2023.2.2 making replace only in selected text?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2023.2.2 making replace in text editor I did not find how can I replace only in selected text : https://prnt.sc/nP9sw9cKkRTT
How ?

ERROR PRINTSCREENS:
In plain php file 1) I try to replace “<tr” 2) with “<trEE” 3) :

[image: Image 1]

Without selected text all “<tr” (count 17) would be replaced

If I select some block of text 4 ):

[image: Image 2]

number of elements is 17 aqnyway 5)
Clicking “Replace all” 6) 17 items  are replaced

I see that option at
[image: Image 3]
has the same value always - it does not change how it works

Comment: It's behind the "three dots menu" -- check there. **P.S.** And use StackOverflow image hosting so that we can see the image right away instead of clicking on a link.

Comment: I try it and it does not work.

Comment: Post a screenshot with what you have there (that would show that you did it correctly). Works OK for me (in a simple PHP file).

Comment: @LazyOne, please look at ERROR PRINTSCREENS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **New UI**. Here it's behind the filter/funnel icon and not "three dots" one (my mistake, not sure why I've mentioned this one in my initial comment when I was clearly using the funnel icon...)

[image]

In a **traditional UI** it's still right there on the screen:

[image]